# What is the difference between standard and language analyzer in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How much will the search improve? For example, if compare standard with Spanish (or any other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language analyzers are tuned for specific languages while the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is language-agnostic but is said to "work pretty well for most languages".

You should go through the following documentation page https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html which explains the language analyzers in more details.

The `standard` analyzer just uses:

- a [`standard` tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html)
- a [`lowercase` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html)

The [`spanish` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#spanish-analyzer) does what the `standard` one does, and adds three more token filters:

- `spanish_stop`
- `spanish_keywords`
- `spanish_stemmer`

So if you know you have spanish text to analyze and you will need to create relevant free-text searches for your users, then I'd go with the `spanish` analyzer